# Does anyone know how to model selection for function on function linear model to find the best subset of functional covariate in R

Tags: model-selection, bic, stepwise-regression, functional-data-analysis, subset

Does anyone know how to model selection for function on function linear model to find the best subset of functional covariate in R

Comment: I'm afraid this is a word salad: it needs context and elaboration to mean anything.  Could you explain?